# How do I set cookies from HTTP header "Set-Cookie: " using curlpp

Tags: curl, curlpp

How can I set this cookie using `curlpp` or `libcurl` when receiving response from server?

I haven't found anything, so do I have to handle it myself? I don't want to set cookies to concrete http request, but something like `InternetSetCookie` in `wininet`.